# Progress component of Ant Design doesnt work with Styled Components

Tags: antd, styled-components

**Problem**: I have types problem using Ant Design with Styled Components, especially with Progress component. I have `"@types/styled-components": "^5.1.24"`. Looks like Progress component is not a component like Button or Input from Ant Design.

Code in editor:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Progress, Button } from 'antd'
export const StyledProgress = styled(Progress)`` // error
export const StyledButton = styled(Button)`` // ok
```

Error code:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   
Overload 1 of 2, '(component: AnyStyledComponent): ThemedStyledFunction<any, DefaultTheme, any, any>', gave the following error.     
Argument of type 'typeof Progress' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyStyledComponent'.
```

I solved this by

```
export const StyledProgress = styled(Progress as unknown as AnyStyledComponent)``
```

But I think its kinda weird

Error example on the screen below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35DpZ.png)

**Expected**: Progress component works with styled-components like any other component from Ant Design

**Received**: Type Error for Progress component

**Question**: Could you tell me please how to solve this problem without this  manipulation?